# Android Studio Chipmunk Upgrade woes (Maybe?)

Tags: android, android-studio

After we upgraded from Bumblebee to Chipmunk, we tried to load a Kotlin project in an effort to adopt someone else's code. This project ran in Bumblebee but does not in Chipmunk???
We are getting unresolved reference errors??? Looks like:

AddURLActivity.kt
Unresolved reference: synthetic
Unresolved reference: synthetic
Unresolved reference: tbAddUrl
Unresolved reference: tbAddUrl
Unresolved reference: addUrlButton
Unresolved reference: addURLTextEdit
Unresolved reference: addURLTextEdit
Unresolved reference: addURLTextEdit

Looks like the root cause of this may be the synthetic (deprecated) import??? BUT I'm not sure what to replace it with???

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think synthetics should be around until [later in 2022](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html?m=1). You should [migrate to view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) though.

Comment: Do you try to clean the project?

Comment: Sorry guys ... yep ... cleaned, invalidated caches, restarted (Also invalidated and restarted after deleting .idea and .gradle). No effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI ... I believe view binding might be the best long term migration BUT looked a little cumbersome so we switched back to the good ole findViewById method.

Thank you